# Compare multiple columns in SQL and determine which are wrong

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables A and B which can be join. Both tables contains many columns but there are 6 columns in both tables, that should contain the same values. These columns are not foreign or primary keys. They are just ordinary columns and they can contain NULL value.

*Lets assume these columns are named like this: A_1 ... A_6, B_1 ... B_7*

My task is to compare all these 6 columns, write them down in the answer and also write down which columns do not match.

Which means that in the query result there must be these 6 columns from A, six columns from B and then another column that says for example:  `"ERROR is in A_5"`

I could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, A_6, 
    B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, B_5, B_6,
    CASE
        WHEN A_1 != B_1 THEN 'ERROR is in A_1'
        WHEN A_2 != B_2 THEN 'ERROR is in A_2'
        WHEN A_3 != B_3 THEN 'ERROR is in A_3'
        WHEN A_4 != B_4 THEN 'ERROR is in A_4'
        WHEN A_5 != B_5 THEN 'ERROR is in A_5'
        WHEN A_6 != B_6 THEN 'ERROR is in A_6'
    END
    as ERROR

FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
   ON A.B_CODE = B.CODE
WHERE
   A_1 != B_1 OR A_2 != B_2 OR A_3 != B_3 OR
   A_4 != B_4 OR A_5 != B_5 ORA_6 != B_6;
```

But there would have to be **51** another when statements, becasue A_1 and A_2 could be wrong both so I would also need to check all pairs and all threes and so on.

**Question is: Is there any way how to do this more efectively and more "cleaner" way?**

The whole problem is in that ERROR column, because it must be in the result

Comment: It would be nice to have an initial script to create tables and fill them

Comment: It very much depends on the data types for your A_1, A_2, etc. columns.  If they are small numbers (e.g. 1 to 10) then the solution could be a lot simpler than if they are all free text.

Comment: Sadly they are free text. And as regards initial script I dont have one. The tables are actually very complex I have tried to make it as easy as possible.

Comment: I don't think you can make it "cleaner" whilst still displaying the reason, it's also worth nothing that you can't compare a NULL with an (in)equality so the expression `A_1 != B_1` will ignore NULL values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do something like this?

```
SELECT
    A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, A_6, 
    B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, B_5, B_6,
    LEFT(ERROR, LEN(ERROR) - 1) AS ERROR
FROM (
SELECT
    A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, A_6, 
    B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, B_5, B_6,
    'Error is in positions ' 
        + CASE WHEN ERROR_1 = 1 THEN '1,' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN ERROR_2 = 1 THEN '2,' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN ERROR_3 = 1 THEN '3,' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN ERROR_4 = 1 THEN '4,' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN ERROR_5 = 1 THEN '5,' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN ERROR_6 = 1 THEN '6,' ELSE '' END AS ERROR
FROM (
SELECT 
    A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, A_6, 
    B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, B_5, B_6,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(A_1, '') != ISNULL(B_1, '') THEN 1 END AS ERROR_1,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(A_2, '') != ISNULL(B_2, '') THEN 1 END AS ERROR_2,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(A_3, '') != ISNULL(B_3, '') THEN 1 END AS ERROR_3,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(A_4, '') != ISNULL(B_4, '') THEN 1 END AS ERROR_4,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(A_5, '') != ISNULL(B_5, '') THEN 1 END AS ERROR_5,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(A_6, '') != ISNULL(B_6, '') THEN 1 END AS ERROR_6
FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN B ON A.B_CODE = B.CODE
WHERE
   A_1 != B_1 OR A_2 != B_2 OR A_3 != B_3 
   OR A_4 != B_4 OR A_5 != B_5 OR A_6 != B_6) I) O;
```

It probably could look a lot nicer than that (by using common-table expressions for a start), but my Oracle SQL is a bit rusty so I kept it simple.

Comment: I think I like your approach, but yes your Oracle is rusty! NVL instead of ISNULL, LENGTH not LEN, and you'll need a SUBSTR instead of LEFT.

Comment: Also, recall that an empty string in Oracle is the same as NULL, so saying `NVL(A_1, '')` is the equivalent of `IF A_1 IS NULL THEN NULL`, which is the equivalent of plain old `A1`. Share and enjoy.

Comment: True, but null values do need to be handled - see Ben's comment on the question. "not(null) != null" evaluates to false, so an error will not be returned where, for example: A_3 = 'abc' and B_3 = null

Comment: I like it too. Thank you all very much.

Comment: You also have to change `+ CASE to || CASE` in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see here is that the A and B tables are not normalized. This makes it tough to compare them in the form given - so, let's use common table expressions to normalize them (note here that I've got A and B as CTE's as well - I'm too lazy to create actual tables, just remove the `A` and `B` CTE's if you need to):

```
WITH A AS (SELECT 99 AS CODE, 1 AS A_1, 2 AS A_2,  3 AS A_3, 4 AS A_4, 5 AS A_5, 6 AS A_6 FROM DUAL),
     B AS (SELECT 99 AS CODE, 1 AS B_1, 2 AS B_2, 13 AS B_3, 4 AS B_4, 5 AS B_5, 6 AS B_6 FROM DUAL),
     A1 AS (SELECT CODE, 1 AS COLNUM_A, A_1 AS VAL_A FROM A),
     A2 AS (SELECT CODE, 2 AS COLNUM_A, A_2 AS VAL_A FROM A),
     A3 AS (SELECT CODE, 3 AS COLNUM_A, A_3 AS VAL_A FROM A),
     A4 AS (SELECT CODE, 4 AS COLNUM_A, A_4 AS VAL_A FROM A),
     A5 AS (SELECT CODE, 5 AS COLNUM_A, A_5 AS VAL_A FROM A),
     A6 AS (SELECT CODE, 6 AS COLNUM_A, A_6 AS VAL_A FROM A),
     B1 AS (SELECT CODE, 1 AS COLNUM_B, B_1 AS VAL_B FROM B),
     B2 AS (SELECT CODE, 2 AS COLNUM_B, B_2 AS VAL_B FROM B),
     B3 AS (SELECT CODE, 3 AS COLNUM_B, B_3 AS VAL_B FROM B),
     B4 AS (SELECT CODE, 4 AS COLNUM_B, B_4 AS VAL_B FROM B),
     B5 AS (SELECT CODE, 5 AS COLNUM_B, B_5 AS VAL_B FROM B),
     B6 AS (SELECT CODE, 6 AS COLNUM_B, B_6 AS VAL_B FROM B)
SELECT 'Error comparing A' || COLNUM_A || ' (value=' || VAL_A || ') to B' || COLNUM_B || ' (value=' || VAL_B || ')' AS ERR_TEXT
  FROM (SELECT * FROM A1 INNER JOIN B1 USING (CODE)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM A2 INNER JOIN B2 USING (CODE)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM A3 INNER JOIN B3 USING (CODE)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM A4 INNER JOIN B4 USING (CODE)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM A5 INNER JOIN B5 USING (CODE)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM A6 INNER JOIN B6 USING (CODE))
  WHERE VAL_A <> VAL_B;
```

This changes the problem from something that is awkward in a relational database (that is, comparing a bunch of different fields in a few rows) to something that is reasonably clean (joining tables and comparing a few columns in many rows).

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d37b/1)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: `where decode(VAL_A, VAL_B, 1, 0) = 0`  would handle null values.